# Any built-in function to change a hexadecimal number to its string equivalent in Java

Tags: java, string, function, hex

Is there any way by which we can directly convert a hexadecimal value to its string equivalent form using some built-in function in java.

Like for example:

Input:"68656c70"

Output:"help"

I know how to do the opposite using built-in function but does for this problem one exist???

Comment: When you say "string equivalent" that suggests you're turning the hex values into bytes, and then applying some string encoding - which encoding are you assuming? Always ASCII?

Comment: it should be in ascii format only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one liner try

```
String hex = "68656c70";
String text = new String(new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray(), 0);
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: +1: that's pretty cunning, I've never seen this use of a BigInteger

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such built-in function. You'll have to do the string split, `parseInt(<bits>, 16);` and then convert to a char manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function but ths may help you:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class RunT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {

            String str = stringToHex("help");

            System.out.println(str);

            String str1 = convertHexToString(str);

            System.out.println(str1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static String stringToHex(String str) {
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            strBuffer.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
        }
        return strBuffer.toString();
    }

    public static String convertHexToString(String hex) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i += 2) {
            String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
            sb.append((char) decimal);
            temp.append(decimal);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: yogesh, i have made the program myself but i just wanted to know if any easy way existed already...thanks for taking the pain of coding the entire program